# Why are commas instead of periods used in this sentence from the Economist?

Tags: punctuation

When reading The Economist, I came across this sentence below in bold. According to grammar, we know a sentence must end up with a full stop, instead of a comma. But in this case, "Mr Trump is the president" and "47% of Americans trust him more than they trust the media" both are sentences, why?

---

> IT WAS almost as if Donald Trump was taunting his Republican
>   colleagues. After tweeting an explosive and wholly unsubstantiated
>   claim against Barack Obama on March 4th—“How low has President Obama
>   gone to tapp [sic] my phones…Bad (or sick) guy!”— the president said
>   it was up to Congress to investigate the matter. “Neither the White
>   House nor the president will comment further,” primly declared his
>   spokesman, Sean Spicer, “until such oversight is conducted.”
>
> Some sort of follow-up is necessary. **Mr Trump is the president, 47% of
>   Americans trust him more than they trust the media (according to a
>   Quinnipiac poll), and his charge against Mr Obama was grave.** If it
>   were shown that his administration illegally snooped on Mr Trump, Mr
>   Obama’s legacy would be disgraced.

*(Source: [Donald Trump’s habit of making accusations without evidence is corrosive](http://www.economist.com/news/united-states/21718569-some-republicans-congress-have-become-little-braver-about-saying-so-donald-trumps))*

Comment: This is an ordinary 'list' of independent clauses conjoined by commas and *and*: "A is a fact, B is a fact, and C is a fact."

Comment: Note the correct use of the Oxford comma in the original.

Comment: Is it still an Oxford comma when separating clauses?  The definition that pops up on Google refers to separating items in a list, which I suppose may technically include a list of clauses, but I never really thought of it as the same.  Particularly, in most circumstances it seems to be the consensus that Oxford commas are optional except when dictated by a style guide.  In this example of clause separation, however, I don't think the commas are optional at all.

Comment: To add to @StoneyB's comment, the *definition* of an "independent clause" is that it can stand alone as a sentence in its own right. What makes it an independent clause rather than a sentence is how it's used. That is, when you take a stand-alone sentence and combine it with other clauses (e.g. with a conjunction), you turn it into an independent clause.

Comment: @DarrenRinger The last comma is optional. Commas are optional except where required, and the only rule that one could imagine would make this required is if "his charge against Mr. Obama was grave" would be a sentence fragment without it. But since it's part of a list that forms a complete sentence, it's not a sentence fragment without the comma. Why would you think it's required?

Comment: Note that sometimes semicolons are used instead of commas in this situation. Especially when each list item is a clause.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz because the way I was taught, in addition to most usage with which I'm familiar, states that commas are required to separate all clauses in a list (despite whether they may be independent).  "Commas are optional except where required" - well, yes.  Therein lies the confusion.  I also admit that I never learned of the "Oxford comma" as an optional thing in any context.  It was always taught as required in my schools - and never called "the Oxford comma".

Comment: English is a 2nd language to me, but I do recall (IIRC) that I was taught to prefer semicolons instead of commas, and that is typically the format I choose when I write formal documents. I never gave much thought to the Oxford comma in 28 years. Good to know!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The sentence uses three clauses and has the structure:

- **A, B, and C**.

The author could have written:

- **A, and B, and C.**
- Mr Trump is the president, **and** 47% of Americans trust him more than they trust the media (according to a Quinnipiac poll), **and** his charge against Mr Obama was grave.

However, usually we prefer  only to  use the word *and*  before the last item in the list. We put a comma between the first two items to show that they are part of the same sentence. We understand a silent *and* there, even though we do not write it or say it.

The writer has put these three clauses together like this because they form a list of three things which—when we consider them together—provide evidence for their claim that "some sort of follow-up is necessary".